# Strange behavior in a perl regexp with global substitution

Tags: regex, perl

Can somone explain me why the output of this small perl script is "foofoo" (and not "foo") ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
my $var="a";
$var=~s/.*/foo/g;
print $var."\n";
```

Without the g option it works as I though it would but why is the global option matching pattern twice ?

In bash output is "foo" as expected

```
echo "a"|sed -e "s/.*/foo/g"
```

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First `.*` matches the a, then it matches the empty string after the a.  Maybe you want `.+`?

Comment: Yes that is it, I am convinced with `$var=~s/^.*/foo/g;` Did not realise it would match empty string but it is actually kind of obvious

Comment: On second thought, * is supposed to be greedy, how comes ?

Comment: @rcout: greediness has to do with times a repetition matches, it won't somehow advance past the end of the string

Answer (score 8):

It is more fun if you try

```
$var=~s/.*?/foo/g;
```

You will get

```
foofoofoo
```

The ? modifier matches 1 or 0 times. If you remove the g, you will get

> fooa

because it will only replace the empty string, the first one it finds. I love perl.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you're using `.*` instead of `.+`

The * modifier tells the regex engine to match (and replace in your example) the string "a", then a zero-length string (and replace it, as well).

You can test this by using this regex in your sample code:

```
$var=~s/(.*)/<$1>/g;
```

You'll then see this output:

```
"<a><>"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you add [re](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html) to your code:

```
use re 'debug';
```

you will see that the regular expression successfully matches twice:

```
Compiling REx `.*'
size 3 Got 28 bytes for offset annotations.
first at 2
   1: STAR(3)
   2:   REG_ANY(0)
   3: END(0)
anchored(MBOL) implicit minlen 0
Offsets: [3]
        2[1] 1[1] 3[0]
Matching REx ".*" against "a"
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=5
   0 <> <a>               |  1:  STAR
                           REG_ANY can match 1 times out of 2147483647...
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=5
   1 <a> <>               |  3:    END
Match successful!
Matching REx ".*" against ""
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=7
   1 <a> <>               |  1:  STAR
                           REG_ANY can match 0 times out of 2147483647...
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=7
   1 <a> <>               |  3:    END
Match successful!
Matching REx ".*" against ""
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=7
   1 <a> <>               |  1:  STAR
                           REG_ANY can match 0 times out of 2147483647...
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=7
   1 <a> <>               |  3:    END
Match possible, but length=0 is smaller than requested=1, failing!
                            failed...
Match failed
foofoo
Freeing REx: `".*"'
```